# Selecting a Random Subset in SQL (Sybase Server IQ)

Tags: sql, random, sap-iq

I'm trying to select a random subset of records using either rand() or newid(), but any time I run the following, I always get the same results back:

```
SELECT *,rand() as rid
INTO #mytable
FROM othertable

select top 10 * from #mytable order by rid
```

I've tried every variation of this, but it seems that sybase server iq always returns the same rand() value when I do it like the above.  When I try to do

```
SELECT * FROM othertable order by newid()
```

I get an error saying it's illegal to use newid() in the order by.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll want to see the random number generator before making calls to rand(). I suggest you put it into a stored proc; you can then seed the random number generator and then execute the first query. `ORDER BY NEWID()` is peculiar to MS SQL Server so it would not work in Sybase. The following thread might be helpful: http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/sybase-l/using-the-function-rand-on-sybase-iq-1547367

Comment: I think you mean "__seed__ the random number generator"...

Answer (score 3):

In Sybase T-SQL, The NEWID() system function generates human-readable, globally unique IDs. Include the NEWID() system function in the ORDER BY clause when issuing the SELECT statement on the target table.

Usage:

```
SELECT top 10 id from TABLE order by NEWID();
```

Answer (score 0):

Random values in the IQ engine are deterministic, force a query through the ASA engine like below (Warning: it is slow if you have many rows).

```
select (select rand() as rnd) from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get random effect by using row_number() function and current time values. Try something like this:

```
with q as (
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() over (order by cPublisher) n, -- getting row number
        DATEPART(ms, now()) t -- getting current ms value
    FROM 
        #mytable
)

select top 10
    *
from
    q
order by 
    -- order by some combination t and n, for example t * n and sort it like char
    cast(t * n as char)
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand why this would give a random order. It seems that `t * n` could easily be monotonically increasing. Maybe you need some kind of random hash of `t` and `n` instead of just `t * n`.