# How to select 10 rows from column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have table in Oracle with column "identification number" which contains identification number for customers. I want to select 10 optionly identity numbers - how to do that; can you help me?

P.S. I'm a newbee to Pl/SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want any **10 random rows**, then just use **ROWNUM**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
   WHERE ROWNUM <=10;
```

If you want 10 rows for a **specific set of values** that meet the condition, then add a **filter predicate**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE identification number IN (1, 2, 3,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

If there are **duplicate values** for `identification number` column, then again add **ROWNUM** to filter the rows, the rows would again be randomly selected:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
   WHERE identification number IN (1, 2, 3,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) 
   AND   ROWNUM <=10;
```

If you want 10 rows in a particular **ORDER**, then you must first sort them and then apply ROWNUM to limit the number of rows in the final output:

```
SELECT * FROM(
   SELECT * FROM table_name 
      WHERE identification number IN (1, 2, 3,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) 
    ORDER BY identification number
             )
  WHERE ROWNUM <=10;
```

You might also be interested in the new **[Top-n row limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25764049/3989608)** feature introduced in Oracle 12c.

Comment: Thank you, I did it with select distinct and rownum <= 10

Comment: @Koshuta Also, remember, distinct is applied on all the columns in the select list and not just column you put after distinct.

Comment: "The first 10 rows" is not the same as ["any 10 random rows."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19153620/712526) Here's a PL SQL implementation: `select * from table where ROWNUM <= 10 ORDER by dbms_random.value;`